# Is it safe to take the address of a temporary?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

In my program, I would like to take the address of a temporary. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Number {
    int value;
    Number(int n) {
        value = n;
    }
};

void print(Number *number) {
    std::cout << number->value << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Number example(123);
    print(&example);
    print(&Number(456)); // Is this safe and reliable?
}
```

This would output:

```
123
456
```

To compile, the `-fpermissive` flag is requied.

Here is my question: is this **safe** and **reliable**? In what possible case could something go wrong?

Comment: You used the  [tag:g++] tag. Does that mean you don't care if it's portable to other compilers?

Comment: @Barmar Good point, I actually do care. They've been removed.

Comment: Reliable by what standard exactly? By the C++ standard, it's not even legal.

Comment: This is not valid C++, how that can be safe or reliable?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley As long as the program compiles on common platforms (specifically Windows, Darwin and Linux), and works reliably

Comment: @Slava I know, but it does compile in `g++`. If it works (reliably), then I'm fine with it.

Comment: You're probably going to keep getting questioned about what you mean by "reliably", given that this is ill-formed.

Comment: The fact that you have to use `-fpermissive` should be a sign that something is hinky about it.

Comment: Why do you ask us then? It can stop to compile any time

Comment: It seems like you really want it to be safe. Why? Why not do things the right way?

Comment: @Barmar There's a good reason for doing this, but yes I could do it the "right way", it's just a lot more effort.

Comment: Passing it by const reference for example is a lot more effort? That raw pointer already shows pretty bad design

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&Number(456)` is an error because the built-in `&` operator cannot be applied to an rvalue.  Since it is an error, it is neither safe nor reliable. "What could go wrong" is that the code could be rejected and/or behave unexpectedly by a compiler which follows the C++ Standard.  You are relying on your compiler supporting some C++-like dialect in which this code is defined.

---

You can output the address of the temporary object in various ways. For example add a member function `auto operator&() { return this; }`  . The overloaded `operator&` can be applied to prvalues of class type.

Another way would be to have a function that is like the opposite of `move`:

```
template<typename T>
T& make_lvalue(T&& n)
{
     return n;
}
```

and then you can do `print(&make_lvalue(Number(456)));`

If you are feeling evil, you could make a global template overload of `operator&`.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me that the object created by `Number(456)` should continue to exist beyond the completion of `make_lvalue`. But I think the c++14 standard supports it: in `[class.temporary]`, "A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call. "

Comment: @Hurkyl indeed, any temporary  persists until (at least) the end of the full-expression it was created by

Answer (score 13):

If your definition of "safe and reliable" includes "will compile and produce the same results if the compiler is updated" then your example is invalid.

Your example is ill-formed in all C++ standards.

This means, even if a compiler can be coerced to accept it now, there is no guarantee that a future update of your compiler will accept it or, if the compiler does accept the code, will produce the same desired effect.

Most compiler vendors have form for supporting non-standard features in compilers, and either removing or altering support of those features in later releases of the compiler.

Consider changing your function so it accepts a `const Number &` rather than a pointer.   A `const` reference CAN be implicitly bound to a temporary without needing to bludgeon the compiler into submission (e.g. with command line options).   A non-`const` reference cannot.

Comment: A non-const reference cannot, but an rvalue reference can again

Comment: Sorry about the late comment. Using `const Number &` will work for `print(Number(456))` but not for `print(&example)` in my code. For one I need `const`, but not for the other. Is it possible to make it work for both, without having two function signatures? Thanks so so much.

Comment: I've created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52269498/5583289) for it.

Answer (score -5):

This is fine but..

```
Number *a;
print(a); // this would be a null ptr error
```

How I would change it is

```
void print(const Number num) // make the paramater const so it doesnt change
{
   std::cout << num.value << std::endl; // note the . instead of -> cuz this is a reference not a pointer
}
```

You would remove the "&" from your code like:

```
Number example(123);
print(example);
print(Number(456));
```

and if you need to pass a pointer you just put a "*" to dereference it.

chasester

Comment: The code that I supplied in my question works fine, it's just matter of safety and reliability. I don't need an alternate solution.

Comment: `Number *a; print(a);` does not produce a null pointer.  `a` is uninitialised, so accessing its value produces undefined behavior.