# C++ function with reference argument that works for lvalues and rvalues

Tags: c++, function, reference, rvalue, lvalue

I would like to have a C++ function which takes an argument, that's a reference, and works for both lvalues and rvalues with **the same syntax**.

Take this example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void triple_lvalue(int &n) {
  n *= 3;
  cout << "Inside function: " << n << endl;
}

void triple_rvalue(int &&n) {
  n *= 3;
  cout << "Inside function: " << n << endl;
}

int main() {
  int n = 3;
  triple_lvalue(n);
  cout << "Outside function: " << n << endl;
  triple_rvalue(5);
}
```

Output:

```
Inside function: 9
Outside function: 9
Inside function: 15
```

This code works. But I need two different functions for my cases, the first where I pass `n` (an lvalue) and `3` (an rvalue). I would like syntax for my function that handles both just fine, without needing to repeat any code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) supposed to do. It could be used with both lvalues and rvalues, and preserves the value category of the function argument.

> Forwarding references are a special kind of references that preserve
>   the value category of a function argument, making it possible to
>   forward it by means of [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).

e.g.

```
template <typename T>
void triple_value(T &&n) {
  n *= 3;
  cout << "Inside function: " << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: note that in a real life scenario you will probably need to use `std::forward` somewhere in that function